# Android OGL ES Definition

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-manifest

My question is:

What happens if you do an android application and do not set an specific OGL ES Version.

Do you use the version 1.0? or the latest supported by the device?.

And is there any way to find this out with an application or something?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES is not required for Android apps to run. If you did an OpenGL ES app you will have to use the API that corresponds to a given OpenGL ES version (i.e. OpengGL ES 1.0 has a completely different API than 2.0)